# React Native : elements of the list stuck together?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, list, react-native

I have an issue: the elements of my list are not spread appart and I don't understand why.
I have 3 elements for each letter and they should be separated.
I think it may have something to do with the fact that these elements are an array inside a list.
Here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbbvi.jpg

Here is my code :

```
        <View style={{ flex: 15, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
          <Text style={[styles.texte201, { marginTop: 50, marginLeft: 80 }]}>
            Glossaire
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: "snow",
              flexDirection: "row",
              shadowColor: "#000000",
              shadowOpacity: 0.2,
              shadowRadius: 10,
              marginLeft: 80,
              marginRight: 80,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginTop: 30,
            }}
          >
            {letter.map((letter) => {
              if (letter.data.length >= 1) {
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: "600",
                        marginLeft: 15,
                        marginRight: 15,
                      }}
                    >
                      {letter.name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              } else {
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: "grey",
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: "600",
                        marginLeft: 15,
                        marginRight: 15,
                      }}
                    >
                      {letter.name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              }
            })}
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 10, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
            {letter.map((letter) => {
              if (letter.data.length >= 1) {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      backgroundColor: "blue",
                      flexDirection: "row",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 90,
                        fontWeight: "200",
                        marginLeft: 15,
                        marginRight: 15,
                      }}
                    >
                      {letter.name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: "600",
                        marginTop: 25,
                        width: "50%",
                      }}
                    >
                      {letter.data}
                      {"\n"}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ marginTop: 50, width: "50%" }}>
                      {letter.description}
                      {"\n"}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              }
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
```

And here is the code of my list:

```
const letter = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "A",
    data: ["Abricot", "Abricot", "Abricot"],
    description: [
      "Un abricot est un fruit",
      "Un abricot est un fruit",
      "Un abricot est un fruit",
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "B",
    data: ["Branche", "Branche", "Branche"],
    description: [
      "Une branche vient d'un arbre",
      "Une branche vient d'un arbre",
      "Une branche vient d'un arbre",
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "C",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "D",
    data: ["Dalle", "Dalle", "Dalle"],
    description: [
      "Une dalle de pierre",
      "Une dalle de pierre",
      "Une dalle de pierre",
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "E",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    name: "F",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    name: "G",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    name: "H",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    name: "I",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    name: "J",
    data: [],
  },

  {
    id: "11",
    name: "K",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    name: "L",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "13",
    name: "M",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "14",
    name: "N",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "15",
    name: "O",
    data: [],
  },

  {
    id: "16",
    name: "P",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "17",
    name: "Q",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "18",
    name: "R",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "19",
    name: "S",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "20",
    name: "T",
    data: [],
  },

  {
    id: "21",
    name: "U",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "22",
    name: "V",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "23",
    name: "W",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "24",
    name: "X",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "25",
    name: "Y",
    data: [],
  },
  {
    id: "26",
    name: "Z",
    data: [],
  },
];
```

If you need it, here is my style :

```
  texte201: {
    color: "#424242",

    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing **{letter.data}** with the following

```
letter.data.map((item) =>  {
    return (
        <Text style={{marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15}}>
            {item}
        </Text>
    )
})
```